# How to use parameteric function arguments

Tags: programming

I have a function defined as follows:

`void turn_leds_on(int col_indx, int bright_1 = BRIGHTNESS, int del_1 = 5, bool dir_1 = true )`

This function is called using MQTT from user to define led's properties, which only first is mandatory ( has no default value ) - MQTT format is : `1,50,40,0`, but can be `1,10`.

Now, to implements this - I read MQTT message and store os into `parameters` as follows:

```
splitter(incoming_msg, 4, parameters); // read 4 parameters
```

when it defined as:

```
    void splitter(char *inputstr, int x, char *output[]) {
  char * pch;
  char *pnts[x];
  int i = 0;

  pch = strtok (inputstr, " ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    output[i] = pch;
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
    i++;
  }
}
```

The problem starts when the user enters only 2 parameters and when passing `parameters` into :

```
if ( atoi(parameters[0]) <= tot_colors - 1 && isDigit(*parameters[0])) { // color num
      if (atoi(parameters[1]) <= 100 && isDigit(*parameters[1])) { //brightness
        if (atoi(parameters[2]) <= 100 && isDigit(*parameters[2])) { //delay between leds
          if (atoi(parameters[3]) <= 1 && isDigit(*parameters[3])) { //direction
            turn_leds_on(atoi(parameters[0]), atoi(parameters[1]), atoi(parameters[2]), atoi(parameters[3]));
```

So the question is: how to pass arguments, and on the other hand when they are not given, to use their default values as defined inside the function?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic

Comment: Hint: Use sscanf and let it scan, convert and check number of parameters.

Comment: `turn_leds_on(3);` will be compiled as `turn_leds_on(3, BRIGHTNESS, 5, true);`

Comment: @Juraj - that is correct, and not what i'm trying to change, but how it when `parameters[i]` is not given

Comment: you can do nothing if don't know the count of items filled in the array

Comment: @Juraj - I know they are 4, but is there a way to define `parameters[i]=NULL`, that when it is entered to the function, and not be an actual value, the defualt arguments will be considered

Comment: yes a pointer to char array can be NULL

Comment: So I checked, but default arguments were not used.